# Is there a way in Angular/Ionic WebApp to read the FCM message data when the app is opened in the background?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire2

I have been trying to do an app that is able to receive updates in real-time from FCM messages. Is irrelevant to this question to explain what I need the data for, so in my example code I am just trying to print (console.log) the data.

I am using Angular, Ionic, and AngularFire

So far I have managed to:

1. Read data from FCM messages when the web app is in the foreground
2. Read data from FCM messages when the web app is in the background AND the user clicks on the notification

But I still need to cover a third case, which is:
3. Read data from FCM messages when the web app is in the background AND the user ignores the notification

I have run out of ideas, and I don't even know if it is possible (I mean, point 3).

This is my code so far:

My app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireMessagingModule } from '@angular/fire/messaging';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('combined-sw.js', {
      enabled: environment.production,
      // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the app is stable
      // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireMessagingModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts omitted because it only has autogenerated code

home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { mergeMapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  token: string

  constructor(
    private afMessaging: AngularFireMessaging
  ) {}

  requestPermission() {
    this.afMessaging.requestPermission
    .pipe(mergeMapTo(this.afMessaging.tokenChanges))
      .subscribe(
        (token) => { 
          console.log('Permission granted! Save to the server!', token); 
          this.token = token;
        },
        (error) => { console.error(error); },  
      );
  }

  listen() {
    console.log("Listening...")
    // this subscription reads notification payload when the app is in foreground
    this.afMessaging.messages
      .subscribe((payload) => { 
        console.log(payload); 
      });
    // this subscription reads notification payload when the app is opened by clicking a notification
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
      console.log(event);
    });
  }
```

And finally, my firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    vapidKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log("Entered SW event listener")
    event.waitUntil(async function () {
        // Exit early if we don't have access to the client.
        // Eg, if it's cross-origin.
        if (!event.clientId) return;

        // Get the client.
        const client = await clients.get(event.clientId);
        // Exit early if we don't get the client.
        // Eg, if it closed.
        if (!client) return;

        console.log("Will 'postMessage' from SW event listener")
        // Send a message to the client.
        client.postMessage({
            msg: "Hey I just got a fetch from you!",
            url: event.request.url
        });

    }());
});
```

Comment: Either create your own third party Cordova plug-in kind of service that runs in the background or listen to this in the server side and update the user when he opens the app

Comment: With option 1) you mean a plug-in to read the data from the service worker that receives the notification?
And as for option 2), I am trying to read the data from the notifications directly, to avoid having to poll the backend for updates, or set up a socket. Maybe what you meant was to force a request to the backend whenever the user bring to foreground the app, which is a good idea, but I have yet to see how hard is that to do in a Web App made in Angular

Comment: No, you have no access to the js at all when the app is in the background. You can only listen the FCM directly